# Stop Concatenating String to Dynamic Array when '#' is Entered by User in C

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I am required to write a code where I constantly read a string input from the user and store it in the same variable. Each time an input is received the string will be concatenated onto a dynamic array (so the dynamic array grows bigger and bigger). It will stop reading the input from the user when the input contains '#'.

Expected inputs and outputs should be:

```
inputs              output
here I am #abc      hereIam
there you are #12   thereyouare
```

Here's the code I've done:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> // for malloc
#include<string.h> // for string funs

int main(void){
    char input1[256];
    char *combined = malloc(sizeof(char));
    int i = 0;

    while (input1[i]!= '#'){  
    // read in the arrays
    printf("Enter a string (max 256 char) ");
    scanf("%256s",input1);

    // find out string lengths
    int len1;
    len1=strlen(input1);

     // allocate an array big enough for both
     combined=realloc(combined, sizeof(char)*(len1));

     //concatenate
     strcat(combined,input1);
    }


    // print
    printf("%s\n",combined);

    return 0;
}
```

This code I have here have several problems:

> 1. I have no idea how to check if elements other than the first element of the user's input is '#' or not.
> 2. Even if the input contains '#', the output will still contain that input where '#' is in it.

Can anyone give me hints on how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: doesn't constantly reading mean you're supposed to use `getch()` for the input?

Comment: `strchr(input1, '#')` returns a pointer to the first `'#'` in the string or `NULL` if there isn't any.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char))` is a severe bug.

Answer (score 1):

You may be making this harder on yourself that need be. While your heading a 2-column output adds a bit of formatting challenge, the easiest way to handle the input and classification (store-it/ignore-it) is with a *character-oriented* approach using `getchar()` or `fgetc()`.

That way you simply continually read from the input and check if the character is a `'#'` or `'\n'`, if so, stop storing characters in your buffer and just read and output the rest. After your loop completes, you simply need to *nul-terminate* your final buffer, compute the whitespace needed between the end of the original and the output of your buffer content, write the spaces and the final buffer and you are done. A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC];
    int c, idx = 0, nc = 0, ws = 0;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    puts ("inputs              output");    /* output headings */
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {        /* read each char until EOF */
        if (c == '#' || c == '\n') {        /* if # or \n, end of storage */
            buf[idx] = 0;                   /* nul-terminate buffer at idx */
            putchar (c);                    /* output delim in orig string */
            nc++;                           /* increment no. of char  */
            while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF) {   /* print rest */
                putchar (c);
                nc++;
            }
            ws = 20 - nc;           /* compute amount of whitespace to col */
            while (ws--)            /* output that many spaces */
                putchar (' ');
            printf ("%s\n", buf);   /* print the stored buffer */
            idx = 0, nc = 0;        /* reset index and counter */
            continue;               /* go get next char */
        }
        else if (isalnum (c))       /* if alnum char add to buffer */
            buf[idx++] = c;
        putchar (c);        /* output all chars until # */
        nc++;               /* increment no. of chars */
    }
    buf[idx] = 0;           /* nul-terminate final line after loop */
    ws = 20 - nc;           /* set number of whitespace needed to 2nd col */
    while (ws--)            /* write that number of spaces */
        putchar (' ');
    printf ("%s\n", buf);   /* output string without whitespace in buf */

    if (fp != stdin)        /* close file if not reading stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/pounddelim.txt
here I am #abc
there you are #12
```

**Example Use/Output**

Running the program on your input produces the *"Expected inputs and outputs"*:

```
$ ./bin/pounddelim <dat/pounddelim.txt
inputs              output
here I am #abc      hereIam
there you are #12   thereyouare
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.